# Is it wrong to give the unit back?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have the following function:

```
  private def constraintToJson(req: => Request[IO])
  : EitherT[IO, Throwable, Unit]
  = {
    val err: EitherT[IO, Throwable, Unit] = EitherT.fromEither[IO](Left(new Exception("Not JSON format request.")))
    req.contentType match {
      case Some(s) =>
        if (s != `Content-Type`(MediaType.`application/json`))
          err
        else
          EitherT.fromEither[IO](Right(()))
      case None =>
        err
    }
  }
```

The question is, it is wrong to return a `Unit` if it is right or there is another choice?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. You do not return a `Unit` but an `EitherT[IO, Throwable, Unit]`. It might help if you state what is your problem, what should your method do, ... [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that returning `Unit` (wrapped into `Either`/`EitherT`) might be OK if this is a kind of the final step of your computation and it actually does not produce any output. In other cases (most probably including yours) you should return some value for the successful case so that you can chain it further. So the main question is: how `constraintToJson` is supposed to be used? The obvious suspect for your case is returning `Request` or its body if the `Content-Type` matches JSON because this is most probably the data that will be used by the next step.

Comment: `constraintToJson` should validate if the request is in json format. Returning request it is a good idea. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Simplified Question

Let me abstract your problem first by removing `IO`. 
The question is whether a method with a signature like the following is useful:

```
def validate[A](a: Request[A]): Either[Error,()] = 
    if(isOk(a.someProperty)) Left(()) else Right("invalid")
```

Noting that `Either[A,()] =:= Option[A]`, this method checks for the presence of any `Error` in the value of the request, and returns this `Error`, if detected.

### What could be done with such a method?

#### Check and exit

We could write a program that checks a `Request`:

```
val someRequest: Request[X] = getRequestFrom("somewhere")

validate(someRequest).toLeft.foreach{error => 
  println("invalid request: " + error
  System.exit(-1)
}
System.exit(0)
```

In this case `validate` has a useful signature.

#### Check and go on

We could also `validate` a request, and then go on to execute it:

```
val someRequest: Request[X] = getRequestFrom("somewhere")

validate(someRequest) match {
  case Left(error) => 
    println("invalid request: " + error)
    System.exit(-1)
  case Right(_)    =>
    println("executing request: " + someRequest.execute)
    System.exit(0)
}
```

While this code works perfectly well, it throws away an argument (`_`) in the second `match` clause. This is an indicator of some bad design. The code within the `case Right(_)` takes the value `someRequest` from outside, and treats it as a valid request because of the way you wrote your code.

If we would call `someReuqest.execute` within the `Left` case, we would probably end up with a runtime exception when executing an invalid `Request`.
Depending on our desired level of rigor, this can be a code smell.

We can improve the code in the following way.

### Using a Non-Unit return type

We can circumvent returning `Unit` by simply returning the checked argument.
This appears to be a bit redundant, and we shall later see how to turn the returned value into something useful.
But let's first look at this option.

```
def validateTyped[A](a: Request[A]): Either[Error,Request[A]] = 
    if(isOk(a.someProperty)) Left(a) else Right("invalid")
```

Then we can write the *Check and go on* code as

```
val someRequest: Request[X] = getRequestFrom("somewhere")

validate(someRequestTyped) match {
  case Left(error) => 
    println("invalid request: " + error)
    System.exit(-1)
  case Right(validatedRequest) =>
    //we now execute the validated request
    println("executing request: " + validatedRequest.execute)
    System.exit(0)
}
```

Now this improves the code a bit.
We don't throw away a returned value anymore in the second `match` clause.
We can execute the `validatedRequest`, because we've read in the documentation of `validateRequest` that a returned `Right` value is well formed, and it may be executed without error.

Looks good, right?
But we can do better.

### Prevent execution of malformed requests

We can still improve it further by totally preventing executing a malformed `Request` by changing our `Request` type.

```
case class Request[A](query: String){
  def validate: Either[Error,ValidRequest[A]] = ???
}

case class ValidRequest[A](query: String){
    def execute: A
}
```

With this code, it is not possible to call `Request.execute` anymore, as a validation now becomes mandatory.
Otherwise the code will not compile.

We also note that the `Right` value returned by `Request.validate` is now needed.
It has become the only source of obtaining a `ValidRequest`.

Now it is impossible to call `execute` a `Request` that isn't validated, yet:

```
val someRequest: Request[X] = getRequestFrom("somewhere")

someRequest.validate match {
  case Left(error) => 
    println("invalid request: " + error)
    System.exit(-1)
  case Right(validatedRequest) =>
    println("executing request: " + validatedRequest.execute)
    System.exit(0)
}
```

### Conclusion

In this way we have turned a strange looking method that returned `Unit` into a method that returns a meaningful and needed value.
In addition it has become impossible to `execute` a `Request` that has not been validated successfully.